# Spark 1.3.0 on YARN: Application failed 2 times due to AM Container

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

When running Spark 1.3.0 Pi example on YARN (Hadoop 2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041) with the following script:

```
# Run on a YARN cluster
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf
/var/home2/test/spark/bin/spark-submit \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--master yarn-cluster \
--executor-memory 3G \
--num-executors 50 \
/var/home2/test/spark/lib/spark-examples-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar \
1000
```

It fails with "Application failed 2 times due to AM Container" message (please see below). As far as I understand, all neccessary information to run Spark application in YARN mode is provided in this launch script. What else should be configured to run on YARN. What is missing? Other reasons for YARN launch to fail?

```
[test@etl-hdp-mgmt pi]$ ./run-pi.sh
Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on classpath

15/04/01 12:59:57 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/04/01 12:59:58 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at etl-hdp-yarn.foo.bar.com/192.168.0.16:8050
15/04/01 12:59:58 INFO yarn.Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 4 NodeManagers
15/04/01 12:59:58 INFO yarn.Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (4096 MB per container)
15/04/01 12:59:58 INFO yarn.Client: Will allocate AM container, with 896 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
15/04/01 12:59:58 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
15/04/01 12:59:58 INFO yarn.Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
15/04/01 12:59:59 WARN hdfs.BlockReaderLocal: The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
15/04/01 12:59:59 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/var/home2/test/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar -> hdfs://foo.bar.com:8020/user/test/.sparkStaging/application_1427875242006_0010/spark-assembly-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar
15/04/01 13:00:01 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/var/home2/test/spark/lib/spark-examples-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar -> hdfs://foo.bar.com:8020/user/test/.sparkStaging/application_1427875242006_0010/spark-examples-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar
15/04/01 13:00:02 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
15/04/01 13:00:03 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: test
15/04/01 13:00:03 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: test
15/04/01 13:00:03 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(test); users with modify permissions: Set(test)
15/04/01 13:00:03 INFO yarn.Client: Submitting application 10 to ResourceManager
15/04/01 13:00:03 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1427875242006_0010
15/04/01 13:00:04 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1427875242006_0010 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/04/01 13:00:04 INFO yarn.Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1427893202566
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://etl-hdp-yarn.foo.bar.com:8088/proxy/application_1427875242006_0010/
     user: test
15/04/01 13:00:05 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1427875242006_0010 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/04/01 13:00:06 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1427875242006_0010 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/04/01 13:00:07 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1427875242006_0010 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/04/01 13:00:08 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1427875242006_0010 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/04/01 13:00:09 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1427875242006_0010 (state: FAILED)
15/04/01 13:00:09 INFO yarn.Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: Application application_1427875242006_0010 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1427875242006_0010_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://etl-hdp-yarn.foo.bar.com:8088/proxy/application_1427875242006_0010/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1427875242006_0010_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Exception message: /mnt/hdfs01/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/test/appcache/application_1427875242006_0010/container_1427875242006_0010_02_000001/launch_container.sh: line 27: $PWD:$PWD/__spark__.jar:$HADOOP_CONF_DIR:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/lib/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/hdp/${hdp.version}/hadoop/lib/hadoop-lzo-0.6.0.${hdp.version}.jar:/etc/hadoop/conf/secure: bad substitution

Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: /mnt/hdfs01/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/test/appcache/application_1427875242006_0010/container_1427875242006_0010_02_000001/launch_container.sh: line 27: $PWD:$PWD/__spark__.jar:$HADOOP_CONF_DIR:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/lib/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/hdp/${hdp.version}/hadoop/lib/hadoop-lzo-0.6.0.${hdp.version}.jar:/etc/hadoop/conf/secure: bad substitution

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1427893202566
     final status: FAILED
     tracking URL: http://etl-hdp-yarn.foo.bar.com:8088/cluster/app/application_1427875242006_0010
     user: test
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:622)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:647)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: check the tracking url and try to find the logs from the container

Comment: Node log: `Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster`

Comment: your classpath is missing the jar that contains this class, try with a fat jar when launching the job.

Comment: `org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster` should be in the jar that `spark-submit` use to create Spark environmet. I don't think application jar should include this class.

Comment: Did you build with YARN support? the error suggests that you didn't

Comment: I have used `pre-built Spark for Hadoop 2.4 and later`, namely spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4.tgz. This pre-built does not have YARN support?

Comment: Hi me too face same problem. I think this may be solved by adding SPARK_CLASSPATH..

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue? what was the solution to it?

Comment: I fixed this issue. Since I'm using spark on windows environment their single quotes it not accepted. So I changed double quotes instead on single quotes at YarnSparkHadoopUtil.scala

Comment: try add -Dhdp.version=xxx

Answer (score 3):

Run

```
yarn logs -applicationId application_1427875242006_0010 > /tmp/application_1427875242006_0010
```

Logs there should indicate why it failed.

"Failed 2 times" happens because when you run in yarn cluster mode, driver runs in AM whose retry is 2 by default.

So your driver is retried twice.

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with @SeanOwen. Follow the Spark Building [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html).

You need to compile spark for YARN using the correct configuration for your hadoop cluster (version,hive support, etc).

The problem won't persist then!

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with spark communicating with Application Master.

The RM and NM talk to each other over RPC so the problem could be launch_container.cmd is not running correctly. Check that the NM has communicating with RM while submitting job

Try adding this to your yarn-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.delete.debug-delay-sec</name>
  <value>1200</value>
</property>
```

This will ensure that the launch_container.cmd from the NM error seen does not get deleted ( will remain around for 20 mins - increase 1200 to a higher number if needed). Now, what you can do is try and run that launch_container.cmd script manually from the container dir and see where it bails out.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar problem. Actually, you do not need to mention --master yarn-cluster when you are running your self-contained application in the cluster.

This problem has been solved on Cloudera forum refer this https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/Issue-running-spark-application-in-Yarn-cluster-mode/td-p/44570